# Where to put UI side affects code in vuex or redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, vuex

I am using a third party webrtc library to achieve video call functionality.

In the library, there are APIs to get a "stream" object. Once I get that (via a call back from the library), I can call `stream.showInElement("#someElement")` to display it on the page.

I wonder how this piece of code fit in Vuex - Where should I put them?

The first option is inside the actions. But ideally actions should be completely separate from the components.

I guess another way is to keep the stream object in the store?? But is store allowed to keep a complex object? I remember in redux we do Object.assign({}, state) all the time, I don't think that stream object can be copied simply that way.

Thanks

Comment: Does more than 1 component need access to `stream`? If not, i think it's okay to keep `stream` in your component. If so, then keeping it in Vuex is an option. For Vuex, you don't need to do `Object.assign`, that's a Redux requirement because it wants immutable state.

Comment: Cool got it. I will keep it inside of my component then.